# Can move row and can edit row at same time in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want both functionality at same time, as shown in attached screenshots.[image: move Row] [image: delete] at same time in `UITableView`.
I set property this `self.myTable.editing = YES;` and

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
```

and

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
```

but I can't, I can only do move row by using these above code.
My questions are.

- Can I use both of them functionality at same time (delete by swapping and moving row by dragging) ?
- If I can't then how can I achieve both at same time (may be I think delete button appear on left side of row)?

Looking of help who face this issue and done stuff like this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you're just probably missing the method below:

**Swift 3:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

**Objective C:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```